# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined как исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скрипт меняет класс навигации при скролле по секциям на странице.

```js
    var menu_selector = ".sticky-tabs";
    function onScroll() {
        var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
        $(menu_selector + " a").each(function () {
            var hash = $(this).attr("href");
            var target = $(hash);
            if (target.position().top <= scroll_top && target.position().top + target.outerHeight() > scroll_top) {
                $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        $("a[href^=#]").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(document).off("scroll");
            $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            var hash = $(this).attr("href");
            var target = $(hash);
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 500, function () {
                window.location.hash = hash;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
    });
```

Есть такой вот скрипт и работает полностью корректно, но консоль при скролле пишет:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (sticky.php:1287)
at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
at m.fn.init.each (jquery.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.onScroll (sticky.php:1284)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js:4)
```

Строка 1287:

```
if (target.position().top <= scroll_top && target.position().top + target.outerHeight() > scroll_top) {
```

Строка 1284:

```
$(menu_selector + " a").each(function(){
```

Не могу понять в чём проблема, подскажите куда копать

Comment: Разметку покажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае target.position() - возвращает undefined, а это возможно только в случае когда target не нашел элементов, удовлетворяющих селектору.

Кроме того в зависимости от версии jQuery при применении этого метода, так же может быть возвращено null, следовательно ошибка может меняться на

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null(…)
```

Comment: Действительно, моя ошибка...
10 раз перепроверял и вот после вашего ответа нашел, опечатка в id у одной из секций. Спасибо